# How to translate "passionate"?

Tags: translation

How do I translate the "passionate"? Synonyms would be hot, romantic, fiery, and so forth.

> The two of them are passionate lovers
>
> They are very passionate in bed
>
> She gave him a passionate kiss

I've come across `热情` and `多情`，but I'm not entirely sure if those are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

热情：enthusiastic, warm

多情：affectionate, loving

热情 is fine, but 热恋 (fiery love) is better for your sentences. An alternative is 激情 which literally means *passionate* with a sense of excitement.

> The two of them are passionate lovers. 他们是**热恋**中的情人。
>
> They are very passionate in bed. 他们在床上充满**激情**。
>
> She gave him a passionate kiss. 她给了他一个**热情**的吻。

Comment: Not to be confused with 基情

Answer (score -2):

From iciba: 马勒也因为其轰轰烈烈的婚外情而出名。

轰轰烈烈的婚外情 passionate extra-marital affairs